# Clearing error messages on clicking in form fields using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a few form fields on my webpage with a button to submit it. If the fields are empty when the error messages are generated, error messages are generated.

Html code :

```
<div class = "contacts">
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <center><text><b>Contact Me!</b></text></center>
            <center><form role="form">
                <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for="inputname"></label>
                    <input type ="text" class = "form-control" id = "inputname" placeholder = "Name" >
                    <span></span>
                </div>


                <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for="inputemail"></label>
                    <input type ="email" class = "form-control" id = "inputemail" placeholder = "Email Address"  >
                    <span></span>
                </div>


                <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for="inputphone"></label>
                    <input type ="number" class = "form-control" id = "inputphone" placeholder = "Phone Number" >
                    <span></span>
                </div>


                <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for="inputmessage"></label>
                    <textarea type ="text" class = "form-control" id = "inputmessage" rows = "5" placeholder = "Message" ></textarea>
                    <span></span>
                </div>

            <div class = "form-group">
                <center><button type="submit">SEND</button></center>
            </div>
        </form></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery script :

```
                $("form").submit (function () {
                    var flag = 0;
                    if ($ ("#inputname").val() === "") {
                        $("#namespan").text("*Enter your name please!").show();
                        flag = 1;


                    }

                    if ($ ("#inputemail").val() === "") {
                        $("#emailspan").text("*Enter your email id please!").show();
                        flag = 1;


                    }

                    if ($ ("#inputphone").val() === "") {
                        $("#phonespan").text("*Enter your phone number please!").show();

                        flag = 1;
                    }

                    if ($ ("#inputmessage").val() === "") {
                        $("#msgspan").text("*Enter your message please!").show();
                        flag = 1;

                    }

                    if (flag === 0){
                        return true;

                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                });
```

How to clear the messages on clicking the form fields to enter something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
$("input, textarea").focus(function(){
    $(this).next("span").empty();
});
```

When you focus on an `input` or `textarea`, this will find the `span` that's next to it, and empty its contents (you can change it to `hide()`).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/Lww8hnfj/

Note: Your code isn't actually working properly because you didn't have proper `id` in your `span`s, so I took the liberty of fixing that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Give each of your input's a class, for example, `.input` and your nearest error message span a class, for example `.error` to make it a little easier. Or...:

```
$('input, textarea').focus(function() { 
    $(this).parent().find('span').hide();
});
```

You could also improve your current script in the same way:

```
var valid = true;
$('input, textarea').each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(this).val() === "") { 
        valid = false;
        $(this).parent().find('span').show();
    }
});
```

Also be careful, as currently your validation will allow inputs to contain just spaces.

Comment: thank you! I had quite overlooked the space in the input part, will fix it!